# Build a Dictionary Class with Static Data (Swift)

Tags: swift, class, dictionary

I need some help to build a Class that will serve as basis for all static content my app will use like States, Cities, Countries, Company classification among others. I'm not expecting those to change over time (or there would be very little change).

As a reference, I'll consider for now Countries and Cities (the logic would be the same for all others)

Class Country:

```
import UIKit

class Country { 
    var name: String 
    var cities: [City]

    init(name:String, cities:[City]) {
        self.name = name
        self.cities = cities
    }
}
```

Class City:

```
import UIKit

class City { 
    var name: String 

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

In my existing code, I use the reference to those 2 classes but I feed the data in my ViewController.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var countryLbl: UILabel!

    var countries = [Country]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self

        // Adding Countries and Cities
        countries.append(Country(name: "UK", cities: [City(name: "London"),City(name: "Manchester"), City(name: "Bristol")]))
        countries.append(Country(name: "USA", cities: [City(name: "New York"),City(name: "Chicago")]))
        countries.append(Country(name: "China", cities: [City(name: "Beijing"),City(name: "Shanghai"), City(name: "Shenzhen"), City(name: "Hong Kong")]))

    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if component == 0 {
            return countries.count
        } else {
            let selectedCountry = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
            return countries[selectedCountry].cities.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if component == 0 {
             return countries[row].name
         } else {
             let selectedCountry = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
             return countries[selectedCountry].cities[row].name
         }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents()

        let selectedCountry = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let selectedCity = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        let cityR = countries[selectedCountry].cities[selectedCity].name

        countryLbl.text = "The right answer was: in \(selectedCountry) in \(cityR)"
    }    
}
```

To make my code cleaner, I wanted to move code below to another class and call it from my ViewController

```
    // Adding Countries and Cities
    countries.append(Country(name: "UK", cities: [City(name: "London"),City(name: "Manchester"), City(name: "Bristol")]))
    countries.append(Country(name: "USA", cities: [City(name: "New York"),City(name: "Chicago")]))
    countries.append(Country(name: "China", cities: [City(name: "Beijing"),City(name: "Shanghai"), City(name: "Shenzhen"), City(name: "Hong Kong")]))

}
```

replaced by something like

```
   let countriesAndCities = Dicitionary.getCountriesAndCities
   // Here I would expect countriesAndCities to have the same content as countries.append(...) above.
```

Is this doable?

Thanks

Comment: Having all of that data as code is far from ideal. Why not put all of the data in a JSON file and then load the data into your structures at runtime?

Comment: hi @maddy, that is a very good suggestion but I have no idea how to do it :-)

Comment: There are countless tutorials on loading JSON in Swift. I'm sure you can easily find plenty of examples.

Comment: Thanks... I forgot that the rest of my code is built based on the structure above and, changing to JSON, would have a major impact. I'll leave JSON as an improvement for my next phase.

Comment: Loading your data from JSON wouldn't change your structures at all.

Comment: maddy is correctly suggesting moving all the country/city data from those lines you want to remove into a json file, and then using that to populate your existing country and city data structures.  As all your data is strings, and therefore compatible with the Decodable protocols it should only take you a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per rmaddy answer you can do your own json file by:

1. Creating your empty fil, save it as json file and in there you can paste the countries and cities.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Kindly see the code how I implement the pickerView in viewController..

[image]

[image]

If you can notice I print the "countryList" in my code below so I can check if the array of countriesJson is not empty. (Please check your logs)

[image]

[image]

Update for 2 components in pickerView.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe4qJ.png)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Aira... I've edited my code with the version you suggested. For some reason, the code never gets "self.countriesJson = countries". Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I tried to troubleshot but couldn't really understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Can i see the countries.json you make? And how you implement the readJson() function in your viewcontroller so I can check?

Comment: Hi Aira, as there is not enough space here, I've added to the question just below Edit Nov 8. Does this help?

Comment: Did you add the readJson() on your viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad before delegating the pickerView? If not kindly include it on viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad before delegating the pickerView 

Comment: Hi Aira, just tried both and still the same errors. Looks like the "if let jsonResult = jsonResult as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, let countries = jsonResult["Countries"] as? [NSDictionary]" is never true and countries are never loaded.

Comment: yes my code is working, kindly see the screenshots below how i implemented my pickerView, I also delegate the pickerView on my storyboard. Can I see the your var countries = [Country]() so i can also check on my end. and can you also print the countriesJson with "Loaded" so I can check if it is loaded.

Comment: Hi Aira, thanks for all the help... I now have Countries populated... Today I'll try to add cities to the second session. Thans again

Comment: Hi @Aira, over the last days I was trying to load the second pickerView with all the cities for that specific country but I couldn't find a way to access cities. Things that I tried: changing NSDictionary to Country, using ["cities"], object etc but none of them worked. Would it be too much to ask your help again on how to populate the column 1 with countries (which is already working) and a second column with cities for that country? thanks

Comment: I added my answer above when using 2 component in pickerView :)